# payment module error 500

Tags: magento-1.9, vps, ioncube

I recently move to a new server. During the new setup, a payment module (vpos), had the ionCube Loader which cannot work with temp URL. Message that the module work with the IP of the domain. 
To check if the magento works ok with orders i rename the folder in app/code/local/mage/module_name_folder so everything loads ok.

My magento site is again on air with the domain point to the new server. 
When i try to rename again the folder to have this module, i get error 500 in checkout page.

```
2017-05-20T09:12:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Empbankr/Model/Emppay.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/username/public_html/commerce/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Mage/Empbankr/Model/Emppay.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/username/public_html/commerce/app/code/local:/home/username/public_html/commerce/app/code/community:/home/username/public_html/commerce/app/code/core:/home/username/public_html/commerce/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php55/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/username/public_html/commerce/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

i have turn compilation off, clear all magento caches automated and manual.
i remove completely memcached through local.xml

The same error again. Does anyone have face the issue opr any idea?

Comment: re-install module.....done

Comment: reboot vps.... done